# How do I prevent my button and text views from overlapping whenever I tilt the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I do this in portrait and landscape view?

I tried to attach the constraints below each other respectively but nothing worked.

Comment: Please, write the code.

Comment: Welcome, but what is your question? Please see [how to ask][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask